# Why mysql command can't be replace by string in shell?

Tags: mysql, shell

```
mysql -u root -ppasswd -e"use test_db;"
```

The command can run in shell console without entering into mysql console.

Why the following two lines can't run in the shell console?

```
str="use test_db;"
mysql -u root -ppasswd -e$str;


ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test_db;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that the shell is splitting your string, so your command ends up being this:

```
mysql -u root -ppasswd -euse test_db;
```

`test_db;` is interpreted as a separate argument, the name of a database.

To solve this problem, use quotes:

```
str="use test_db;"
mysql -u root -ppasswd -e"$str"
```

I removed the semicolon as it seems like you're specifying it twice. For a single command, I don't think you need it at all but I guess your script will be more complicated than this in reality.

As an aside, you can skip the `use db_name` command by specifying a database (as you were doing by accident):

```
str="select col1, col2 from table"
mysql -u root -ppasswd -e"$str" test_db
```

Answer (score 1):

Because shell split your string str. 
You should write like this:

```
mysql -u root -ppasswd -e"$str"
```

Or you will get this:

```
mysql -u root -ppasswd -euse test_db
```